# Arm assembly traversing through a label with .word

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to go through a array of integers to sort each integer into one of five categories. I am writing in arm assembly and so far this is what I have came up with this to traverse through the array and then work with the integer.

```
        .data
str1:   .asciz  "Lost Generation: %d"
str2:   .asciz  "Greatest Generation: %d"
str3:   .asciz  "Baby Boomer Generation: %d"
str4:   .asciz  "Generation X: %d"
str5:   .asciz  "Generation Y: %d"
str6:   .asciz  "Generation Z: %d"
str7:   .asciz  "Not Applicable: %d"
ary:    .word   100,40,5
        .equ    arysize,(. - ary)/4

        .text
        .global main

main:   stmfd   sp!,{lr}
        mov     r0,#0

read:   cmp     r0,arysize
        beq     end         
        ldr     r1,=ary
        add     r2,r1,r2
        ldr     r1,[r2]
        add     r0,r0,#1
        b       lg

lg:     cmp     r1,#127
        ble     lg2
        add     r12,r12,#1

lg2:    cmp     r1,#102
        blt     gg
        add     r6,r6,#1

gg:     cmp     r1,#101
        ble     gg2
        b       @not applicable

gg2:    cmp     r1,#93
        blt     bb
        add     r7,r7,#1



end:    ldmfd   sp!,{lr}
        mov     pc,lr
```

I am just curious as if I am going the right direction. My current plan is to have the current integer so for example the first one would be 100. I would want to have 100 in a register then compare it through a series of comparisons to see which category to place it into. Thank you!

Comment: Do `ldr r1, =ary` *outside* the loop, so you can `add r1, #4` inside the loop to advance to the next element.

Comment: So would i delete the `add r2,r1,r2` and `ldr r1,[r2]` lines and replace them with the `add r1,#4`? Thank you! @PeterCordes